# Keep getting a "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup" when attempting to google plus login on my web app

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, google-plus

I'm trying to implement Google plus sign up on my web app and I followed the google docs to set up the sign up however when I attempt a signup after accepting permissions and using the access token returned to me any api restcall I make returns the Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup error. I have already signed up my app with a ouath 2.0 key, so I don't seem to get what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code.

Cient Side:

```
const clientId = "5XXX000XX.apps.googleusercontent.com";
const apiKey = "AIzaSyCAXE5JSa36jcC*X7HV40SBcIWBiVGUTBE";
const scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";
let accessToken = null;

function initer() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
  // alert("Hello init");
  if ($("#authorize-button").length > 0) {
    $("#authorize-button").click(onLoginClick);
  }
}

function onLoginClick() {
  // $("#modalLoading").modal();
  // alert("yeah");
  gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false }, onConnect);
}

function onConnect(authResult) {
  // alert("On connect");
  if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    alert("Hey");
    accessToken = authResult.access_token;
    triggerLogin();
  } else {
    alert("Error");
  }
}

triggerLogin = function() {
  alert("Triggering login");
  $("#modalLoading").modal();
  $.ajax({
    url: window.config.site_root + "account/google_login",
    type: "POST",
    data: "access_token=" + accessToken,
    success: onLogin,
    error() {
      onError("Logging In", "starting your session");
    },
  });
};

onLogin = function(login) {
  alert("Login start");
  $("#modalLoading").modal("hide");
  if (login.operation) {
    location.reload();
  } else {
    alert("Register will start");
    triggerRegistration();
  }
};

triggerRegistration = function() {
  $("#modalLoading").modal();
  $.ajax({
    url: window.config.site_root + "account/google_registration",
    type: "POST",
    data: "access_token=" + accessToken,
    success: onRegistration,
    error() {
      alert("An Error");
    },
  });
};

onRegistration = function(data) {
  alert("Handling register");
  $("#modalLoading").modal("hide");
  if (data.account_exists) {
    stage.showErrorModal(
      "Account already registered",
      "There is already an account with that email address, are you sure you created an account using this login method?",
    );
  } else if (data.operation) {
    alert("Login now");
    triggerLogin();
  } else {
    alert("Error");
    onError("Registering", "creating your account");
  }
};
```

Here is my server side code

```
 public function google_registration()
            {
                $access_token = (isset($_POST["access_token"]) && !empty($_POST["access_token"])) ? $_POST["access_token"] : null;


                $name = null;
                $email = null;
                $account_id = null;
                $picture = null;
                $gender = null;

                try
                {
                    if($access_token)
                    {
                        $me = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=".$access_token);
                        if($me)
                        {
                            $me = json_decode($me);
                            $name = $me->name.formatted;
                            $email = $me->email;
                            $account_id = $me->id;
                            $picture = $me->image;
                            $gender = ($me->gender == "female") ? 1 : 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception $error)
                {
                    // let the system handle the error quietly.
                }
                return $this->service_registration("google", $name, $email, $account_id, $picture, $gender);

            }
```

Answer (score 35):

I too ran into the same error - "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup".

I went and checked my google developer console under APIs for the project associated with the API key/ auth key, eg, `https://console.developers.google.com/project/<your app id>/apiui/api`. The status for Google+API was set to OFF. I turned it ON.

I then got another access token, and then tried with the new one. It worked, ie, the error was gone and I got the profile details. To cross-check if that was indeed the cause of the error, I went back to console and disabled Google+ API. But now, I get the error:

"Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."

So, I am not 100% sure that it was the turning on/off of the Google+ API in my developer console, but do ensure that this is turned on. Also, wait a few minutes after turning on, and ensure that you get a fresh token each time before trying it.

Comment: Enabling API at Google Console Worked! Thanks mate :)

Comment: One note: if your project is a google scrip instead you'll want to go to https://script.google.com/home/usersettings

Answer (score 14):

[image: google api]

Make sure you have Google+ Api here enabled.

**Without it you will get errors like:**

```
"domain": "usageLimits",
"reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
"message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
```

**To enable it:**

1) open https://console.developers.google.com

2) choose your project (top right corner)

3) search for "Google+ API" in search box and enable it if it is not enabled already.

Comment: I don't find this screen? Where is it ?

Comment: I didn't put you minus, I just ask a question. I get this error but in my quota screen, i am below maximum.

Comment: ok. I found it. But limit is set to 10 000 and I just test...below 20 times. So It doesn't fix my pb. Thx

Comment: This seems to be outdated again

Answer (score 13):

This issue happens when you are already logged in and still try to login again and again. I faced same error so did some experiments 1) I opened website on my mobile and everything was fine. 2) Then i tried on another laptop and used different gmail account to login and it again worked fine. 3) On my first laptop i tied again by clicking "Signin" button i got same error, so i opened google.com then logged out completely and then tried again, this time it worked. So i believe, Issue is clicking login button again and again without logout.

I am not sure if this is a really a issue, but atleast this is what i found. I am still trying, trying and trying , will post if i found anything else.

Cheers !!

Comment: This was definitely my problem as well. Was very confusing because the API's were all enabled, I was passing everything in correctly, but that error message is terrible! I opened an Incognito window and it worked immediately. Logged out in the normal brower, then back in again and it again worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You have to add the `apiKey` with the URL:

```
$curl = curl_init( 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=AIza3834-Key' );
```

Comment: That doesn't sound great from a security perspective, but hey, it worked. +1

Answer (score 9):

So I ran into this issue and the above two methods/solutions (enabling API access, and signing out of accounts) did not work for me because for google+ signin you have to pass in the access token in the authorization header of the http call.

Here's how you do it via jQuery:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET", 
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me",
      headers: {
       "Authorization":"Bearer " + {access_token},
      }
    });
```

It seems your issue is with the server side code where you pass in access_token in the params (which is not necessary).

Here's my attempt on what the PHP implementation would look like:

```
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
 'method'=>"GET",
 'header'=>"Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token 
 )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me', false, $context);'
```

Comment: Although the official documentation did state that you can pass the access_token as a Query parameter or in the header, I always received that error when passed it in the Query.It only worked when passed as a header.  It says:  "include the access token in a request to the API by including either an access_token query parameter or an Authorization: Bearer HTTP header". Here is the link: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: Yup. Google's docs are simply wrong, here. You *can't* put the access token in the URL parameters, at least not for all endpoints (you definitely can for some endpoints). For example, I can't when trying to get a file from Google Drive. It's probably best to just assume you can never put the token in the URL, and *always* put it in the headers.

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully you're sending that access token over https! It might be worth considering using the code instead and doing an exchange on the server side for an access token, for improved security if nothing else, there's some documentation on that approach here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

With regards to the problem you're seeing, it seems like the access token is bad, or not making it through correctly. Can you check the access token that you receive against the tokeninfo endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token= - that should show valid information. Nothing stands out as being off in the code, but if the token is getting mangled you might see a similar error.

Answer (score 1):

I got have the same issue, The solution is: set APIKEY

Comment: For references:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/api-keys

Answer (score 1):

I was also desperate, and finally I managed to find a solution. The only problem is to add the correct api token linked to your app, in my case was the browser token, and it all works.

Example: I wanted to have all the events associated with my calendar

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendar_id}/events?&key={api_key}

maybe I will help someone who is having the same problem.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use `access_token` to fetch a returning user's name and picture when they already logged in during a prior session. After running into the `"unauthenticated use"` error message, this is what finally worked via cURL in PHP.

```
//initialize provider specific params for oauth2
$access_token = <fetched from app database from last login> //remember to never expose this to users
$api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me';
$headers = [
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token
];

//send curl request
$curl = curl_init();
$curl_opts = [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_POST => 0, //GET
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_URL => $api_url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
];
curl_setopt_array($curl, $curl_opts);
$curl_response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
$curl_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

//parse curl response from provider into name and icon fields for my app
$name = $curl_response['displayName'];
$icon = $curl_response['image']['url'];
```

Note that `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` (for returning users via `access_token`) and `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` (for initial login via `code`) return the user name and picture in different fields/structures.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem on JavaScript side (Client Side).
In my case it was necessary to add `API_KEY` to `gapi.client.init()`

Full my function:

```
async function initClient () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const API_KEY = "YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY"
    const CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID"
    const DISCOVERY_DOCS = ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest']
    const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'

    const initData = { apiKey: API_KEY, clientId: CLIENT_ID, discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS, scope: SCOPES }

    gapi.client.init(initData).then(function () {
        // YOUR CODE HERE
    }, function (error) {
      reject(new Error('Reject Error: ' + error))
    })
      .catch(err => console.log('Catch Error', err))
  })
}
```

`API_KEY` and `CLIENT_ID` can be taken from [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) (Google Cloud Platform -> APIs & Services -> Credentials -> Credentials [Tab])

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it happened at a specific time of the day, After spending few hours finally found that my daily quota limit (**Queries per 100 seconds**) was exceeded at that time because of a high number of requests. so it was throwing the error. I have contacted google support to increase them.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I was using an old access token. You must keep in mind that access tokens have a short life span, so you must use the refresh token to generate a new access token. Example (using a PHP Class):

```
// Get the access token from DB or filesystem
$accessToken = $this->getAccessToken();
// Set the access token
$this->client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

// Refresh the token if it's expired.
if ($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $this->client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($this->client->getRefreshToken());
    // Save the new access token to DB or filesystem
    $this->saveAccessToken($this->client->getAccessToken());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had same problem and found out what was wrong.

When you enable your Google Plus API from your Library, there is extra steps to completely activate. You have to click "Manage" button in the Google Plus API Library page and fill up two question answer and submit. That's all!!

This fixed my issue and I hope its fixes yours as well. Here is the screenshot of that page where i was taken after I clicked "Manage" button which says "Add credentials to your project".

[image: Google Plus API Library Add credentials to your project]

Answer (score 0):

**I'm getting the following error:**

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use 
requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use 
requires signup."
 }
}
```

I'm not sure but i think its caused in my case on the OAuth consent Screen of the Google Developers Console, there is this message,

***The user cap limits the number of users that can grant permission to your app when requesting unapproved sensitive or restricted scopes. The user cap applies over the entire lifetime of the project, and it cannot be reset or changed. Verified apps will still display the user cap on this page, but the user cap does not apply if you are requesting only approved sensitive or restricted scopes. If your users are seeing the "unverified app" screen , it is because your OAuth request includes additional scopes that haven't been approved.***

I'm requesting restricted scopes:

```
private val SCOPES: List<String> = arrayListOf(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE, DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA, DriveScopes.DRIVE)
```

Although my app is in development it seems to require verification, I think over the lifetime of the development of my app i have signed in over 100 times. (See OAuth user quotas)
    https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?authuser=0

**I Guess i have to verify my App Does anyone know if this is the case...?**

Answer (score 0):

I think (at least for some) this error could be leading them in the wrong direction. In my case, my API call was working, then suddenly stopped. Here was my thought process while working through this error, hopefully it will help someone:

**OBSERVATIONS**

- New error was produced

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

- This occurred during a test attempting to send an update to the Google Calendar API with the following call:

```
service.events().patch(calendarId='primary', eventId=id, sendNotifications=True, body=update).execute()
```

- This occurred shortly after I updated the data in my `time_start` variable referenced in the json that gets sent to google:

```
    update = {
        'start': {
            'dateTime': time_start,  # Specifically this variable (time_start) was changed
            'timeZone': time_zone,
        },
        'end': {
            'dateTime': time_end,
            'timeZone': time_zone,
        },
        'description': description,
    }
```

- The information in my `time_start` variable changed from:
  `2020-05-13T17:06:42-07:00` to `2020-05-13T17:06:42` (note the missing UTC offset)

**ACTIONS**

- Updated my code populating `time_start` to include the missing UTC offset that was being passed to google calendar API.

**RESULTS**

- The payload successfully transmitted to google calendar and my event was patched with the update

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has gotten this issue while using Drive API (in my case, using Python as programming language), this can also occur due to an incorrect metadata update. Here is my error report:

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

This was, in essence, due to the fact that I was trying to alter both `copyRequiresWriterPermission` and `viewersCanCopyContent` fields over an `application/vnd.google-apps.folder`, which is not allowed.

No clue about why Google chose to send an error report so unrelated to the actual error.

Comment: Where can I see that?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the scope you use for Drive API is labelled restricted.
You can make a limited number of requests to get file data/content.
Once you have reached the limit you have to get another access_token for the existing session. It is like having refresh_token.

You can wrap your code that sends requests to get files in `try...catch`
If that error is thrown you can `requestAccessToken`.

NOTE: For refreshing the access token in an existing session, you do not need to ask for content again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).