# Spreadsheet custom function returns error while in script editor not

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-fusion-tables

I've created custom function in spreadsheet, which gets data from Fusion table.

```
function getData(){
  var tableId = "********";
  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tableId + ' LIMIT 100';
  var response = FusionTables.Query.sql(sql);
  Logger.log(response);
  return response;
}
```

It works when I run the function in the Script editor, but when I call the function in a cell in the spreadsheet it returns:
`Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.`

Is there different approach to the data from spreadsheet and from script editor or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you for any idea!

Comment: any help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335503/keep-getting-a-daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-exceeded-continued-use-requ ?

Comment: unfortunately no, my Fusion Tables API is enabled. Furthermore that guy has problem with access from his own website, I am trying to connect directly with Advanced Google Services - Fusion Tables v2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom functions can not user services that can access users data. The docs have a list of what services can be used in custom functions.

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services

There is a work around for this by using the Execution API. The basic idea is you publish your script as an execution api and call it from your custom function. Check out a demo I put together on this at:

> https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-Authorized-Custom-Function

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question what I am doing wrong. Unfortunately, your script looks little bit outdated - there is few this that google deprecated. Nevertheless I have new way to think about it.

Comment: what is depreciated? I use this method live in production.

Comment: I found this one - ScriptApp.getProjectKey(), newly substituted with ScriptApp.getScriptId()