# Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded Google Api Calendar

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-console-developer

I'm testing a sample code. It has always worked but suddenly i get:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

Again, it has ALWAYS worked. **Nothing changed**. I know to set console dev stuff and blablabla. I would like to know the cause of this issue.

This is my script:

```
  gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': 'xxxxxxxx',

        'discoveryDocs': ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"],
        'clientId': 'xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
      }).then(function() {


            gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
              'calendarId': 'primary',
              'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
              'showDeleted': false,
              'singleEvents': true,
              'maxResults': 10,
              'orderBy': 'startTime' //from input
            }).then(function(response) {
             var events = response.result.items;

              if (events.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                  var event = events[i];
                  var when = event.start.dateTime;
                  if (!when) {
                    when = event.start.date;
                  }

                  appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')created at '+ event.created);



                }
              } else {
                appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
              }

            });


    });
function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep getting a "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup" when attempting to google plus login on my web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335503/keep-getting-a-daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-exceeded-continued-use-requ)

Comment: yeah i read a lot of response obviously, 
If I wrote the question is because I still have not solved it

Answer (score 5):

Even if you are not authenticating to Calendar as a user, you should create a client project and attach your key to requests so that Google has a project to "bill" the quota usage against. This will prevent these kind of issues in the future. See [Google's help article](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862?hl=en) but the general steps would be:

1) Create a Google API Project at https://console.developers.google.com.
2) Enable Calendar API for the project.
3) Get the API key under API Manager > Credentials.
4) Include the key as a parameter for all your Calendar API requests. E.g.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events?key={your_key}
```

Comment: yeah i know how to do that. In fact, i can get all my events with "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly" scope, but i need also to use "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar" and when using it i get the error. I added api key.

Comment: These are all details you need to put in your question since we don't know if you're doing oauth, what scopes you are using and if you are sending a key. May be good to go back and add now for completeness sake.

Comment: added my script to question

Comment: I ran into the same issue, and while it is likely true that if he was missing scope, he should add scope, but i was getting a similar error for a different API because i had not been instantiating with my API key despite having a token.

Answer (score 2):

Solved with "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly" scope! It works again without any changes. Maybe it needs some time, but "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar" still not working.

Comment: how did you do it? i'm using same for drive. readonly on public folder, and still getting an error.