# Getting dailyLimitExceededUnreg message during development of my app

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm building an app that uses Google APIs (Drive and Sheets). I'm currently writing code to utilize refresh tokens. So, I'm actually generating unauthorized (401 error) requests on purpose to test my code. Until... I hit this daily unauthorized limit. I'm not sure what I can do. What does "Continued use requires signup." actually mean? Signup for what? Do I need to register my app? Do I have to signup for Google Cloud billing? Any way to avoid this while developing an app?

(Note - I can successfully call the APIs before I hit this limit - when I started working on refresh token processing, so it's nothing related to how I'm generating requests - also I see the same thing in POSTMan).

Any help appreciated...

Comment: What is your exact error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/44248616/1503886

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246011/daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-exceeded-google-api-calendar/44248616#44248616 - I'm purposefully triggering the 401 Unauthorized request in order to test my refresh token code, but I'm running into Google's restriction:

Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup error

But, I want to know if there is a different approach that I ought to take.

Answer (score 1):

> Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires
>   signup

This error message usually indicates that you are trying to perform requests without an authorization token or API key.

It is intended behavior from Google's side to avoid abuse.

If you intentionally induce this situation, you have to wait until the next day for your quota to be reset, see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/147470780).