# Google signin using Angular JS Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-plus

I'am using [this link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) to implement google login in my AngularJS site and I am able to get id_token using

```
var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
```

then I'm passing this to php file and do like below,

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=.$id_token
```

I'm getting this error,

```
"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup"
```

Note: I enabled google+ API in my console too.

Can anyone explain id_token is same as accesstoken ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep getting a "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup" when attempting to google plus login on my web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335503/keep-getting-a-daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-exceeded-continued-use-requ)

Comment: @Claies question updated

Comment: @Claies im passing id_token js variable to php file to obtain user details

Comment: @AbhishekVyas i tried all said in that url but none works

Comment: @Claies leave php i just executed above url in browser still getting error "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup"

Comment: @Claies obtained id_token is access_token right? or there is any other way obtain that im new to  this