# Keep getting The API returned an error: Error: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup

Tags: node.js, express, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I followed the https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs tutorial and I got it to list the files in onto the console but when I try to return res.data.files it gives me undefined value and errors out with: The API returned an error:

> Error: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use
>   requires signup.

Tried to return it from the listFiles function

```
            var express = require("express");
            var router = express.Router();
            const fs = require('fs');
            const readline = require('readline');
            const {google} = require('googleapis');

            // If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
            const SCOPES = [
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly', 
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
            ];
            // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
            // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
            // time.
            const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';



            /**
             * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
             * given callback function.
             * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
             * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
             */
            function authorize(credentials, callback) {
            const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
            const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
                client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

            // Check if we have previously stored a token.
            fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
                if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
                oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
                callback(oAuth2Client);
            });
            }

            /**
             * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
             * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
             * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
             * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
             */
            function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
            const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
                access_type: 'offline',
                scope: SCOPES,
            });
            console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
            const rl = readline.createInterface({
                input: process.stdin,
                output: process.stdout,
            });
            rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
                rl.close();
                oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
                if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
                oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
                // Store the token to disk for later program executions
                fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
                    if (err) return console.error(err);
                    console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
                });
                callback(oAuth2Client);
                });
            });
            }

            /**
             * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
             * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
             */
            function listFiles(auth) {



            const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
                drive.files.list({
                pageSize: 10,
                fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
            }, (err, res) => {
                if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                console.log(res.data.files[0].id)
                return res.data.files
                const files = res.data.files;
                return files
                if (files.length) {
                console.log('Files:');
                files.map((file) => {
                    console.log('=======================================================')
                    console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
                    console.log('=======================================================')
                });
                } else {
                console.log('No files found.');
                }
            });
            //   return drive.files.list
            }



            router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
                // res.send("getting files please wait");
                // Load client secrets from a local file.


                fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
                    if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
                    // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
                    authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
                    var ans  = listFiles()
                    console.log('====>')
                    console.log(ans)
                    // res.send(ans)
                });
            });

            module.exports = router;
```

What I am getting:

> ====> undefined The API returned an error: Error: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.
>   1EMcY5pRCsAfWPfZt0DtuBCHV2FLNAwBM

What I should get:

> ====> 1EMcY5pRCsAfWPfZt0DtuBCHV2FLNAwBM 1EMcY5pRCsAfWPfZt0DtuBCHV2FLNAwBM

Comment: Duplicate for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335503/keep-getting-a-daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-exceeded-continued-use-requ

Answer (score 1):

You have used up all of your daily API calls for your key. This is a measure put in place so you don't flood their system.