# Google Calendar Webhook Payload Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am trying to integrate google calendar with my micro service in Jersey.

I have configured the connection following Google documentation and at the moment I am able to create and remove webhooks, and create remove and list events.

However, when I create an event in Google Calendar, the payload of the webhook that Calendar itself hit my endpoint with instead of notifying me the creation of such event it says:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

The scope of the connection to the project is CALENDAR (that should give read/write permission to the project) and in total I don't get to 100 requests, when the limit should be of 100K.
OAuth2.0 should also be correctly configured as I am able to do all the basic CRUD operations.

On Google-side I have enabled the Calendar API(s) and still no luck.

Any idea on what it can be or what I can try to do?

Thanks

Comment: Have you obtained a new access token since enabling the Calendar API?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I have just tried to delete the client in google console and create a new set of credentials, but I get the same response... it feels like is a problem on the Google side rather than authentication on mine... thanks anyway...

Comment: Have you checked out the different solutions [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335503/keep-getting-a-daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-exceeded-continued-use-requ)?

Answer (score 0):

Found the (silly) solution on my own... tried to access the uri resource link that Google provided using postman with OAuth2.0 as authentication method. And automatically retrieved the web hook... I was expecting a Json payload, not a link to the payload itself...